# Bookmarklet that saves web page as-is and provides a link to it?

Tags: javascript, java, web-browser, web-services, bookmark

I recall there was a site that provided a java bookmarlet that would save the web page as-is (not just a .jpg screenshot), and instantly provide you a link where you could view it. The service I'm describing could make EXACT copy of the page that you have opened in your browser. So, for example, if you're logged in, it would also show your nickname in a nickname section of the page and such. Not as if the page was re-opened by a bot that accessed the page and then saved it. It also didn't require me to install any programs, apps or anything, it only required a bookmark.

It is not getpocket.com or evernote.com or archive.org